# How can I create column headers in the key with pot.legend in python? An example can be seen in the graph provided ( ‘column headers’ circled in red)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[example can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9KAD.jpg)

Please look at the example photo where I’ve circled what I’m talking about in red. So the graph compares different materials, each having 2 curves. The curves will have markers of the same shape but one curve will have solid markers and the other open markers. But the solid and open markers represent different properties which is why they have a ‘header’. I’m trying to figure out how to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the trick:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

N = 10

x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)

p1 ,= ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(N), linestyle = '', markerfacecolor = "black", markeredgecolor = "black", marker = "<")
p2 ,= ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(N), linestyle = '', markerfacecolor = "black", markeredgecolor = "black", marker = "s")
p3 ,= ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(N), linestyle = '', markerfacecolor = "black", markeredgecolor = "black", marker = "o")
p4 ,= ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(N), linestyle = '', markerfacecolor = "white", markeredgecolor = "black", marker = "<")
p5 ,= ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(N), linestyle = '', markerfacecolor = "white", markeredgecolor = "black", marker = "s")
p6 ,= ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(N), linestyle = '', markerfacecolor = "white", markeredgecolor = "black", marker = "o")

blank = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)

legend_handle = [blank, blank, blank, blank, blank, p1, p2, p3, blank, p4, p5, p6]

label0 = ["", r"$1-Pt$", r"$2-Pt$", r"$Bulk$"]
label1 = [r"$G'(\omega)$"]
label2 = [r"$G''(\omega)$"]

label_empty = [""]

legend_labels = np.concatenate([label0, label1, label_empty * 3, label2, label_empty * 3]) 

ax.legend(legend_handle, legend_labels, loc = 'best', ncol = 3,  handletextpad = -2)

plt.xlabel(r"$\omega$")

plt.ylabel(r"$G'(\omega), G'(\omega) (Pa)$")

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]